# Loop constructing the URLs in a little parser-script: a seven liner needs some help!

Tags: php, url, loops

howdy - good morning Community!

i want to parse the site - and get the results out of it:

see this URL [here - a swiss-server - head over to this site](http://www.educa.ch/dyn/79363.asp?action=search) 
 where i want to loop over - see this page here - i want to access the sub-pages in order to get the information that is shown in the "detail-pages!"

therefore i need to loop over the line 2 - don ´ i!?

```
 <?php
 $data = file_get_contents('[here we have to add the URL ');
 $regex = '/Page 1 of (.+?) results/';
 preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
 var_dump($match);
 echo $match[1];
 ?>
```

in order to get the details of the sub-pages - plz have a look above!!

just help me with this seven-liner  ;)

Fritz The Cat

Comment: what are you trying to extract after you find number of subpages?

Comment: hello Esryl - many thanks for the reply. I want to extract the little (!!) data-set. It is a 5 or 6 liner (in each of the sub-pages) This can be done with DomDocument!? It would be  great if you can give me a hint how to combine the fetching - part with the parsing part of this little project. See one of the sub-page - it has only a few lines http://www.educa.ch/dyn/79376.asp?id=2704  - i am pretty new to php and have only a little experience!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to reconstruct the sub-page URLs.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$match[1];$i++)
{
  $url = "http://www.example.com/page?page={$i}";
  // access new sub-page, extract necessary data
}
```

Comment: hello esryl many many thanks - thats it! You are g reat! Mille Grazie! Fritz The Cat!

Comment: btw - how would a parser-part look like-. If i get the pages i want to do parsing with DomDocument. That seems to be a good parser-solution!

Comment: I personally use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ as it is nice and easy to use for most things.

Comment: hello Esryl - many many thanks! I will have a closer look at this sourceforge-Project! I guess that this will help me! Mille Grazie! Fritz-The-Cat